# Instance state to keep button visibility

Tags: android, android-intent

How do I keep button Visibility when returning from another activity?

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = btVis.edit();
        edit.putString("btS1",btSub1.getVisibility()+"");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS,0);
        int btS1 = Integer.parseInt("View." +btVis.getString("btS1",""));
        btSub1.setVisibility(btS1);    
    }
```

I get an error cause `setVisibility` needs to be in format `View.(VISIBILITY)` for example. But I parsed `btS1` as an `int` in the format `View.(VISIBILITY)` so I dont know why it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one in onResume() method.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS,0);
    int visibility = Integer.parseInt(btVis.getString("btS1",""));
    switch(visibility){
    case View.VISIBLE: //make button visible
    break;
    case View.INVISIBLE: //make button invisible
    break;
    }

}
```

Make sure to commit editor at the end of onStop() method

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `editor.commit();` which means your int was never actually saved.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = btVis.edit();
    edit.putString("btS1",btSub1.getVisibility()+"");
    editor.commit();
}
```

### Edit:

I see you also did something wrong

```
int btS1 = Integer.parseInt("View." +btVis.getString("btS1",""));
```

While you do get the id via the class `View`, you don't need to get it from your shared prefs that way. You already just stored the `Integer` that is referred to in View.GONE and View.Visisble.

To make this work you just need:

```
int btS1 = Integer.parseInt(btVis.getString("btS1",""));
```

But I don't see why you would parse it to a `String` and then parse it back to an `int`. Also I would do the saving on `OnPause` instead of `OnStop`. So completely reworked you should do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = btVis.edit();
    edit.putInt("btS1", btSub1.getVisibility());
    edit.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences btVis = getSharedPreferences(BUTT_VIS, 0);
    int btS1 = btVis.getInt("btS1", 0);
    btSub1.setVisibility(btS1);    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reminder, sadly the error "Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE" still remains

Comment: Might be that it's not saved properly onStop, try onPause instead. Also a fallback to default 0 would help the app never crashing